# upload multiple files angular and springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, multipart

Im trying to upload multiple files to springboot server from angular but I dont know why this code dont work

Im getting this error in browser

> POST http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles 400
> core.js:6140 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles", ok: false, …}

springboot restapi:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadfiles")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public void uploadingPost(@RequestParam("uploadingfiles") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles) throws IOException {
    for(MultipartFile uploadedFile : uploadingFiles) {
        File file = new File("C:\\" + uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadedFile.transferTo(file);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

upload service:

```
upload(fileslist: File[]) {
const formData: any = new FormData();
const files: Array<File> = fileslist;
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  formData.append('uploadingfiles', files[i]);
}
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles', formData, {
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'json'
});

return this.http.request(req);
}
```

uploadcomponent:

```
filesPicked(files: File) {
Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, file => {
  this.uploadPaths.push(file.webkitRelativePath);
  console.log("file-----" + file.webkitRelativePath);
 
});
this.uploadService.upload(this.uploadPaths).subscribe(file=>{})
}
```

html:

```
<input id="selectConnector" type="file" #selectConnector class="fileLoader" (change)="filesPicked(selectConnector.files)"
  webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    @PostMapping("/uploadfiles")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMap> uploadingPost(@RequestPart List<MultipartFile> files) {
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
            files.stream().forEach(file -> {
                ...
            });
        }
        ...
    }
```